# 2 navigation button on navbar (bootstrap mobile)

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I set 2 navigation buttons for mobile design on the navbar using bootstrap 3?

In this example, the left button (hamburger) collapses the menu and the right button (magnifying glass) performs a search. https://filmlimani.com/the-dark-knight.html (mobile version)

[image: film limani mobile screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

You can paste HTML-code of your search button before `<button class="navbar-toggle"...` in `<div class="navbar-header">`
And you need to get icons-set (for example [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)). With font-awesome you code will be

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" type="button">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

Then you need edit styles, and set a js-function to this button